# Adding text / input box rendering to Access for a guided user interface experience

Tags: ms-access, vba, vb6

For software used in a call centre guiding agents through a set script they must follow while on telephone calls, with the script branching dependant on answers to questions given - My system uses a MS Access / VBA front end (isnt web based due to speed, phone integration), 'call scripting' is coded in VBA when needed, but what if i want move to a more complete solution?

Is hosting a HTML/ms webbrowser control the obvious platform to build call scripting on?

A manager view will also be needed allowing managers to create scripts, divide it into parts, specify routing rules that determines the path through the script, link input boxes (ie question answers) back to database fields, specify validation rules as well.

Thinking about the complexities of building the manager view that translates the intended script into HTML/Javascript, is creating my own simple doc description language with tags for just the features i need and a 'rendering engine' in VBA a solution you might consider for this?

Ive thought about creating scripts out of standard Access controls, using relational table structure to hold the info of what controls relate to what parts of scripts, validation, routing options etc but i think due to Access' lack of runtime control creation this will be more painful than a rendering engine that takes a script written in my own doc desc language and displaying it.

What suggestions have you for the implementation of this?

Comment: What's wrong with keeping the Access front end? In other words, if it ain't broke, don't fix it. You haven't identified anything that's broken, so far as I can see.

Comment: Im not suggesting no longer using Access. I just want to implement a call sripting system that can be changed by users who arnt vba programmers. changes to the call script requires vba experience - this is the downside, a lot of the other day to day tasks associated with my system can be passed of to knowledgable users, this is the big one that can not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual user interface requirements of the user-facing part of your system seem to be pretty minimal (ask question, get answer, branch to "next" question).  I don't think there's any "obvious" platform to use.  As always, a browser based system makes it easier for geographically scattered users to use a centralized system but will probably cost more in terms of development.

The manager-facing part of the application is more interesting and for that I'd probably suggest a desktop application rather than a browser based one.  I can see this relying on a lot of drag-and-drop and line-drawing type functionality and that kind of stuff is still easier to do on the desktop, at least in my opinion.

Assuming that you can clearly define the kinds of question routing and decision points that a script has, and these decisions are relatively simple, I probably would write your own specification for how a survey is represented.  The manager-facing application would create, edit, and save a specification and the user-facing application would read and step through one.

Given my personal skill set, I'd probably write both applications in Delphi, develop an XML format to represent the survey specification, and consider either XML or relational storage for the back end depending on what you actually wind up doing with the data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm inclined to agree that a web interface is optimal for something like this, however WPF is a great alternative as well with many of the advantages of a web interface along with the power of a desktop application. Both web and WPF would give you considerable amount of control over how the application looks and feels, leveraged with all the power of the .NET framework. One drawback of a web app is that you have less ability to interact with the phone system directly, but I'm sure that's a problem that can be mitigated fairly easily with some AJAX. A big plus for the web platform option is that you'll have access to tons of client-side interactivity libraries like jQuery, which will allow you to polish the application with greater ease; with WPF you would likely find yourself paying for a lot of the fancy UI controls.

Comment: .NET - im at the beginning of learning this at the moment, right at the beginning! Learning curve too steep for me to implement right now i think. O and i need Win2000 compatibility :-(

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a few survey and question (test creating) systems built in access. I don’t see any real issues in using access as opposed to whatever system.

The advantage of HTML or text based systems is they tend to support a more dynamic type of screens.

On the other hand, for questions and display of text, in access a great trick is to place a sub-form control on a form, and then at runtime simply “set” what form is to be displayed in that sub-form (the source object properity). In fact, in access 2010, the nav control does exactly that and it displays forms as a sub-form.

Also for access 2010 we can create web based applications. In this video you can see that the half way mark, I switch to running the application in a standard browser.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

However, the above means little here, as I not sure what you mean by some type of rendering engine. Each question + response is simply going to be some text on a screen, and thus you can simply display/change that text by changing the underlying reocrdset.

And, if you want nice formatted text with different fonts etc, well access 2007 now has support for rich text (markup text). So I don’t think you really need dynamic screen creating. Between changing the record source to display whatever text you want, and that of being able to display different forms (templates) on the fly by changing the sub-forms “source object”, you can well change part of your screen to display different text boxes with very little code.

On the other hand, if you have all of the .net tools and want to create a browser based application then you are free to do so. I suppose you could also wait for access 2010 to create a browser application.

If you willing to keep this simple, then access is a great choice. If you need a browser based application, then I don't access is the choice here.